# How do I use Super CSV on a delimited file that does not use a quote character?

Tags: java, csv, supercsv

I'm using Super CSV to parse a pipe ("|") separated file. The file does not use "text qualifiers", or what Super CSV calls a quote character. The problem is that Super CSV [requires](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/supercsv/prefs/CsvPreference.Builder.html#CsvPreference.Builder%28org.supercsv.prefs.CsvPreference%29) a quote character. I don't see a way to skip this, or provide a null character. Currently I'm passing some wacky unicode character that hopefully never appears in the input file.

Is there a way to have Super CSV parse a file without using a quote character?

Comment: If that API does not accept `|` as a delimiter, it is broken.  But I suspect that it does.

Comment: No, the quote character is used to handle embedded delimiters (`|` in this case). I'll look into this for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that you don't have control of how the file to parse is written, and that it will never contain embedded pipe characters in the data?

The solutions I can see are:

- Use a character that will never appear in your file (as you've suggested). This is a little dodgy, but will work.
- Supply your own Tokenizer when you construct your Reader (you can copy the [Super CSV implementation](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/xref/org/supercsv/io/Tokenizer.html) and just remove the quoting functionality).
- Send us a [feature request](https://sourceforge.net/p/supercsv/feature-requests/) and we'll consider adding it. It may be simply a case of adding another preference which disables quoting when parsing.

I'll have a think about this, and see if I can think of the best way to achieve this.

Comment: I think using a separate strategy where quoting is not supported is a better choice since this will increase the speed of reading - a string.split() is enough to tokenize.. it should be part of the framework

Answer (score -1):

Use the delimiter character as the quote character. E.g.:

```
CsvPreference cp = new CsvPreference('|'/*quote char*/,'|'/*delimiter char*/, "\n");
```